# VIM, how to paste something in the command line of vim?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vim, editor, text-editor

So I would like to know how can I paste from system clipboard to vim command line; I mean for example I'm in normal mode and I hit Shift+: and then I want to paste there something from my clipboard. yank and paste do not work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+paste+command+line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select what you want in vim using <kbd>v</kbd>.

Then press <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>*</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd> to copy your selection in the clipboard.